# Resources identifiers to screen configurations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-identifiers

I'm developing an app and my current task is to support different screen sizes.  My problem is that a lot of devices have the same identifiers.

For example, `large-hdpi` supports Nexus 7, Galaxy Note & Galaxy Tab.  But in the Note and Tab all layout dips are bigger than in the Nexus, so we use `large-hdpi-v11` for Nexus 7 and `large-hdpi-v8` for the Galaxy Note and Tab.

I do not believe this is the best match for those devices; using the version as an identifier displays a warning even on Logcat.

```
[2013-03-13 18:48:14 - iba commons] 'Large Screen, API Level 8' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.
[2013-03-13 18:48:14 - iba commons] Displaying it with ', , Locale Language ___Region __, sw480dp, w480dp, h800dp, Large Screen, Long screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, Medium Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Hidden navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 800x480, API Level 17' which is compatible, but will actually be displayed with another more specific version of the layout.
```

What's is the best way to identify those devices without specifying a version?

Comment: Why are you trying to specifically identify those devices to start with?

Comment: Just because they doesn't fit the window properly as designed on layout-large-hdpi, I can send pics to show how they behave in Galaxy Tab and Nexus 7 that are both large-hdpi